# Variable Substitution in YAML not performed before loading into Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

```
vars:
  version: 0.0.1
  path:
    train: ./data/for-training-cnn
    test: ./data/for-testing-cnn
    model: "./data/model/sandbox"
test: ${vars.path.model}
```

**YML file**

```
import yaml
from yaml import Loader

config = yaml.load(open("this.yml"), Loader=Loader)
print(config['test']) # Output -> "${vars.path.model}" not "./data/model/sandbox"
```

**PY file**

Shouldn't config['test'] contain `./data/model/sandbox`, not `${vars.path.model}`. Why isn't the variable being substituted?

I used YAMLLint to verify that my syntax is correct.
Printing out config yeilds the expected nested dictionary, but the variable still isn't substituted with its value.

I understand that YAML, like JSON, is a data format that does no processing. But, then how does [this](https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/v3/tutorials/nel_emerson/project.yml) work? Their code doesn't seem to do any processing of the YAML file, but perhaps I missed it.

Comment: Why would you expect the YAML loader to perform variable substitution? If you want to do that, you will need to use some sort of templating package (or write your own code to perform the substitution).

Comment: @larsks edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: The answer to "how does this work?" isn't one we can answer. It has nothing to do with YAML -- whatever is consuming that YAML file must have some sort of templating support. Read through the project documentation and see what processes `project.yml`.